# Categorizing a data frame in R by both vertically and horizontally using certain column and totaling another column

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

```
df <- data.frame(
  cat = c("a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c", "a", "b", "c"),
  Cost = c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8),
  range = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 2)
)
```

from the code above I need to pivot the data such as interval [0,3), [3,6),[6,9) and [9,Inf) is on the vertical side (this interval is applied on range) and horizontally I need the column cat "a", "b" and "c". and I need I need sum of Cost in pivot.

first the interval can be created like this .

```
values<-c(0,3,6,9,Inf)
df$Interval<-findInterval((df$range),values,right = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0):

An approach using the **tidyverse**, `pivot_wider` to reshape and `group_by` followed by `summarize` to `sum` up the values.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

pivot_wider(df, names_from=cat, values_from=Cost) %>% 
  group_by(grp = cut(range, breaks=c(seq(0, max(range), 3), Inf), right=F)) %>% 
  summarize(range = paste(min(range), max(range)), 
            across(a:c, ~ sum(.x, na.rm=T)))
# A tibble: 4 × 5
  grp     range     a     b     c
  <fct>   <chr> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1 [0,3)   1 2       3    11     8
2 [3,6)   3 5       6     7     5
3 [6,9)   6 8       3     4     8
4 [9,Inf) 9 10      6     0     5
```

With **base R**

```
res <- reshape(df, idvar="range", timevar="cat", dir="wide")

res <- cbind(res, grp = cut(res$range, 
  breaks = c(seq(0, max(res$range), 3), Inf), 
  right = F))

aggregate(cbind(Cost.a, Cost.b, Cost.c) ~ grp, res, sum, na.rm=T, 
  na.action=na.pass)
      grp Cost.a Cost.b Cost.c
1   [0,3)      3     11      8
2   [3,6)      6      7      5
3   [6,9)      3      4      8
4 [9,Inf)      6      0      5
```

Comment: is it possible using base package